# Using the cloud service to trasform a picture using a neural algorithm?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Yesterday I tried to transform a picture in the artistic style using **CNNs based on A Neural Algorithm of Artistic Style by Leon A. Gatys, Alexander S. Ecker, and Matthias Bethge** using a recent Torch implemenation,as it is explained here :

https://github.com/mbartoli/neural-animation

it started the conversion correctly,the problem is that the process is very time consuming,after 1 hour of elaboration a simple picture was not fully transformed. And I have to trasform 1615 pictures. What's the solution here ? Can I use the **Google Cloud Platform** to make this operation faster ? Or some other kind of Cloud service ? Using my Home PC is not the right solution. If I can use the **cloud** power,how can I configure everything ? let me know,thanks.

Comment: Although your question looks valid at first sight it does not meet SO [minimal site criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will fit better at a sister site. You can select one or more from [> here <](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Looks to me "code optimization" appraoch.

Answer (score 0):

Using (Google Cloud Platform) GCP here would seem to be a good use case.  If we were to boil it down to what you have ... you have an application which is CPU intensive that takes a long time to run.  Depending on the nature of the application, it may run faster for any single given instance by having more CPUs and/or more RAM.  GCP allows YOU to choose the size of the machine on which your application runs.  You can choose from VERY small to VERY large.  The distinction is how much you are willing to pay.  Remember, you only pay for what you use.  If an application takes an hour to run on a machine with price X but takes 30 minutes on a different machine with price 2X then the cost will still only be X but you will have a result in 30 minutes rather than an hour.  You would switch off the machine after the 30 minutes to prevent charging.

Since you also said that you have MANY images to process, this is where you can take advantage of horizontal scale.  Instead of having just one machine where the application takes an hour on each machine and all results are serialized.... you can create an array of machines where each machine is processing one picture.  So if you had 50 machines, at the end of one hour you would have 50 images processed instead of one.

As for how to get this all going ... I'm afraid that is a much bigger story and one where a read of the GCP documentation will help tremendously.  I suggest you read and have a play and THEN if you have specific questions, the community can try and provide specific answers.